# Unable to submit Mosaico mailings

Tags: civimail, mosaico

We have recently started using mosaico and despite test mailings being sent and received successfully we cant get any 'live'messages to send, to individuals or groups.

When you hit submit it just gets stuck as 'submitting' without progressing or actually sending any mailings.

Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the log files? Or maybe install https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer ext to view error log messages in civicrm UI

Comment: Check your mailer settings at /civicrm/admin/mail?reset=1. Set the batch limit to, say, 300 or so.